# How to align a control side-to-side?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm making dynamic radio buttons by using ASP.NET. Where there a validation control that I want to align side of this radios buttons.

Code:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList
                ID="tiposeg"
                runat="server"
                RepeatColumns="3">
                <asp:ListItem>a</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>b/asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList> 
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator15" 
                ControlToValidate="tiposeg" 
                ErrorMessage='<% # foo.ErrorMessages.EmptyField %>'
                runat="server"
                />
```

The problem is: if making by using `<asp:RadioButtonList`, the `<asp:RequiredFieldValidator` is displayed into next line, unlike if I do it by using "HTML pure", that is displayed side of control (without need to use CSS). I hope this is clear. Thanks in adavnce.

**EDIT**
in other words, it's possible put the `<span>` generated by `asp:RequiredFieldValidator` inside `<table>` generated by `<asp:RadioButtonList`?

**EDIT 2**

My current **ASP.NET** code;

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList 
    ID="RadioButtonList1"
    runat="server"
    RepeatColumns="3">
    <asp:ListItem>abcd</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>xyz</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>

     </li>
     <li style="display:inline">

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
    ID="ReqiredFieldValidator1"
    runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="RadioButtonList1"
    ErrorMessage="select atleast one radiobutton!"
    />
```

The form:

What I'm getting:

[image]

What I'm expecting:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you really want to arrange the radio buttons in a grid with multiple rows and columns? If not, delete the `RepeatColumns` attribute and add `RepeatLayout="Flow"` and `RepeatDirection="Horizontal"`:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="RadioButtonList1"
    RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
```

This will render the radio buttons without a containing `<table>`, so the validator will appear to the right of the last radio button.

Comment: Perfect! exactly it what I'd looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Could you achieve what you want by putting the controls in DIVs and floating them both left?

Comment: Can you give me a simple example? I have no experience CSS and know a bit about older HTML.